# does votingapi_set_votes handles voting and unvoting

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

does votingapi_set_votes handles voting and unvoting. I will try to use the same logic as this [Drupal Creating Votes in Voting API Through Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124627/drupal-creating-votes-in-voting-api-through-code/36307632#36307632) to create a vote. What i am asking is how to handle voting and unvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you add votes using `votingapi_set_votes` and delete votes using `votingapi_delete_votes`.

For both these functions you need a base criteria, something like this.

```
$criteria = array(
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'entity_id' => $node->nid,
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'value_type' => 'points',
  'tag' => 'vote',
);
```

For setting vote you need its value, which usually differs from criteria only by value field.

```
$votes = $copy_of_criteria;
$votes['value'] = 666;
```

Then `votingapi_set_votes($votes, $criteria)` will **delete** all votes matching `$criteria`, and then add new votes (specified by `$votes`). This function also takes care of recalculating votes cache (i.e. aggregated values).

For deleting votes ("unvote") you firstly need to select required votes and then pass them into the `votingapi_delete_votes` function:

```
$votes = votingapi_select_votes($criteria);
votingapi_delete_votes($votes);
```

This function does not recalculates voting cache, so you need to call `votingapi_recalculate_results('node', $node->nid)`.